# Cut a string in lines with a max number of character

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"

I have a container which contains this sentence. My container has a width and text has font-size.

I want to divide my sentence in several lines without cutting words.

Check my code :

```
    var containerWidth = 200;
    var el = document.getElementById('content'); //get the sentence
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');  // get the font-size
    var fontSize = parseInt(style); 
    var charPerLine = limit = Math.floor(containerWidth / fontSize); // get the maximum number of characters per line

    el.parentNode.removeChild(el); //remove the sentence

    var wordsTab = el.innerHTML.split(' '); //split each words into an array
    var txt = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < wordsTab.length; i++){          
        if(charPerLine - wordsTab[i].length >= 0){ 
            txt += wordsTab[i] + ' '; // add the word to a string
            charPerLine -= wordsTab[i].length;  // Here I substract the word length to the number max per line
        }

        else{ //Here I create a new div (new line) with the text inside
            var line = document.createElement('div');
            line.innerHTML = txt;
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(line);
            //Reset values for the new line
            txt="";
            charPerLine = limit;
        }   
    }
```

Check this out : https://jsfiddle.net/5omg4078/1/

In this example my container width is 200px and the font-size is 15px, so the the number max of characters = 200/15 = 13. I can put 13 characters. "Lorem" & "ipsum" count 10 characters. "dolor" counts 5 characters so with "lorem ipsum" it is higher than 13 -> it goes in the else and create a new line.

```
// In this case : 
wordsTab[0] = "lorem"; wordsTab[1] = "ipsum"; wordsTab[3] = "dolor"
```

However, as you can see, when it goes in the else the word does not appear in the next line and I know why it is because it is not added to `txt += wordsTab[i] + ' ';` and the i is directly incremented (in this example it takes the value of i=4, so the i=3 is forgotten).

What I would like is when it goes in the else, we apply a i-1 (don't know if it is the good way).

Thank you

Comment: I think you want `txt = wordsTab[i] + ' ';` in the else instead of `txt = "";`.

Comment: I put txt="" in the else in order to reset the value for the new line

Comment: But you want the word in there otherwise it will be forgotten. Notice that I used `=` rather than `+=`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Ok @AndrewMorton you are right ! Can you check this : https://jsfiddle.net/5omg4078/3/ ? Why the last word does not appear ? Thank you

Comment: @connexo The last word of the sentence is not displayed because it does not go in the else. Do you know how to resolve this ? jsfiddle.net/5omg4078/3

Comment: I mean what are you trying to achieve visually? This seems to be a problem caused by the solution. http://www.mbtmag.com/article/2011/12/solution-caused-problems-and-how-prevent-them

Comment: @Seabon You could put `if (txt.length > 0) { /* insert code to add line */ }` after the loop.